# sync audio to multi-part avchd

Tags: audio, sync

I've recorded a 2 hour interview session, with external audio. My camcorder broke the video up into 2GB chungs (MTS files).

I'd like to sync up the audio with all the clips so I can easily use sections from any of them in the final cut/edit.

Is the best bet to just load all the clips into Premiere Elements and sync up the audio and then export the 2 hours to an intermediary file? If so, what's the best export settings? I don't need to reencode the video, just merge and replace the audio with the synced external audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the time code is reliable and your camera didn't drop frames, it should be as simple as laying them back to back and then syncing the audio.  I normally recommend syncing to a point in the beginning and then checking if it still lines up at the end.

If not, a couple of factors could be in play.  It could be that the timecode is just off from the recording speeds not matching exactly or it could be that a frame drop resulted in an issue.  Clocks mismatched is fairly easy to deal with as you can simply apply a minor speed correction, but if a frame is dropped, you'll need to find where the audio went out of sync and correct manually.

The easiest way I've found to identify which is the problem is to adjust the speed and then check a few places in the middle.  If they are all in sync, you probably guessed right, if not, then it must be a sudden change from a dropped frame.

As for making use of the long clip with the sync applied.  I normally handle this kind of a thing by reusing the sequence as a source.  It saves on having to output the full file and still lets you work with the clip as if it was a single file.  I don't know for sure if Premiere Elements supports nested sequences though as I've been using Premiere Pro since long before there was a Premiere Elements.

Comment: Thanks AJ, but it looks like PrE doesn't have nested sequenses. http://forums.adobe.com/message/5178075 What would you reccomend as an intermediate export file?

Comment: In that case, your best bet is probably to use an external stitching tool to append the files without a re-encode if possible (depends on file format and I'm not that up to date on current software since I always nest sequences).  You could output the audio as an uncompressed WAV file to maximize quality of that output and then use the stitch program to attach the WAV as the audio portion of the stitched video.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be to just split the audio track where the video track splits. Then I can link each video/audio chuck to each other.

Marked the other answer as correct just to give him the points for trying to help.